# I apparently have a defective hard drive

Tags: imac, data-recovery

I noticed my Mac ticking like a clock and turned it off - it obviously hadn't switched off properly.

When I reboot I get a flashing question mark, so I tried booting with ctrl+R. 
Computer does not find Startup Disk.

In Mac OS X Utilities -> Disk Utility when I select my HDD no *First aid* is available but if I select restore and my HDD as the source with Mac OS X Base System as my destination - will I lose files by erasing the Base System / what will happen?

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: No I do not. I only have backups to single files/folders on various external HDs/sticks but not a comprehensive backup of my entire computer.

Comment: The first thing to do is get that hard disk out & stop trying to boot from it, if you ever hope to get any recoverable data from it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you I will find someone who can do that.

Comment: Mac OS X Base System is the mini-OS for Recovery HD. Don't erase it.